# Find $\Pr(X≤x,Y>y)$ given the joint CDF $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$

Tags: probability, solution-verification

> Given a joint CDF, $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$, for the vector of continuous random variables $\boldsymbol{X}=(X,Y)$, find $\Pr(X≤x,Y>y)$

Can you please check if my solution is correct?

My attempt:

Let $B=\{X≤x\}\cap\{ Y>y\}$
$$
\Pr(B)=\lim_{y\to\infty}F_{X,Y}(x,y)\cdot \Pr(Y>y)
$$
$$
\Longrightarrow \lim_{y\to\infty}[F_{X,Y}(x,y)]\cdot 
[1-\Pr(Y≤y)]\\
\Longrightarrow \lim_{y\to\infty}[F_{X,Y}(x,y)]
\cdot \lim_{x\to \infty}
[1-F_{XY}(x,y)]
$$
where $ \lim_{x\to \infty}F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ and $ \lim_{y\to \infty}F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ are the marginal CDF's of $ F_{X,Y}(x,y)$

I am not sure with this solution, I might have made some unnecessary assumptions with the formula. Thank you.

Comment: You have assumed that $X,Y$ are independent . If that is not given in the question , I don't think you should assume that.

Comment: @Mr.Gandalf Sauron should I use the complement of $B$ first? So that there will be no intersection and I can use the probability on union of events, or is this another unnecessary assumption?

Comment: Hint: what can you say about $P(X\leq x, Y\leq y)+P(X\leq x, Y>y)$?

Comment: @Andreas Lenz I think that they are the probability of the union of the two? (Which is the whole $y$ axis and a portion of $x$)?  So it would be equal to $1-\Pr(X≤x,\infty)=1-F_{XY}(x,\infty)?$

Comment: Andreas' comment tells you that you can say $P(X\leq x,Y>y)=(\lim_{y\to\infty}F(x,y))-F(x,y)$

Comment: @qcpz Almost, the union of the two events is $\{X\leq x\}$. Can you use this to solve the problem?

Comment: Oh My mistake for assuming that having $\lim_{y\to \infty}F(x,y)$ spans the whole plane , the answer would be as Mr. Gandalf Sauron said. It is quite different from my final answer, I think that they would be the same if both events are independent as Mr. Sauron said.  That answer has no assumptions on independence so I will adopt that way of solving these kinds of problem.

Comment: Only a remark on your notation of the joint CDF. You write $F_{XY}$ but I would interpret that as the CDF of rv $XY$. Personally I would rather go for $F_{X,Y}$.

Comment: @drhab I'm not aware of that, Im using the notation on my book. I'll fix that thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is reasonable to assume that $(X,Y)$ does have a joint density . If so it will be given by $$\frac{\partial^{2}F(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y}$$. You can refer to wikipedia for this. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution](http://Joint%20pdf.)

Just scroll down a little and you will see it for the continuous case.

Now you can actually integrate this out.

$$P(X\leq x, Y>y)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}\int_{y}^{\infty}\frac{\partial^{2}F(x,y)}{\partial x\partial y}\,dydx$$

Else , You can use disjoint union of events as suggested in the comments.

$P(X\leq x,Y\leq y)+P(X\leq x , Y> y)=P(X\leq x)$

Thus $\displaystyle P(X\leq x,Y>y)=\left(\lim_{y\to\infty}F(x,y)\right)-F(x,y)$

And yes, If $X,Y$ are independent, then what you have done is totally correct. But just a little advice, it will be better and perhaps more mathematically correct if you do not write as "$\infty$" . But use $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am yet to discover that topic  on the book, I'll analyze that later, for now I am just curious if I can find the probability using simple tricks.

Comment: I have edited to include your efforts too. Please check

Comment: @qcpz . I have included a link to wiki for the expression for joint pdf using joint cdf. You can refer to it. Otherwise you can refer to https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/461/jointdistributions.pdf . Or some book , like Sheldon Ross , Taylor and Karlin would also do.!!

Comment: Ok thank you very much